# WordPress: how to trigger action after I login through external site?

Tags: wordpress

Currently, I am building an SSO for WordPress using Wild Apricot. This SSO allows login through their site and after login, it redirects back to the WP site with login to the site. So, how to detect that action after login?
I tried with "wp_login" action but no luck.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: check for the code in functions.php

Comment: @charankumar Basically, it sets an auth and cookie after login so add_action( 'set_auth_cookie', 'my_cookie_action', 10, 5 ); helped me. :)